# How to query with with filter classifications in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Looking for a way to filter `clothes` based on their `labels`, the `labels` need to be considered for their classifications, such that different classification all needs to be satisfied (AND), same classification is joined (OR).

E.g. The following expectation can be satisfied:

Query: (`Blue(classification: Color)` or `Green(classification: Color)`) and `On Sale(classification: Discount)`

or

Query: `Blue(classification: Color)` and (`Aloha(classification: Style)` or `Knit(classification: Style)`)

[image]

```
class Clothes < ApplicationRecord
  string :name

  has_many :clothes_label
end

class ClothesLabel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :clothes
  belongs_to :label
end

class Label < ApplicationRecord
  string :name # blue, aloha, knit, black
  string :classification # color, style

  has_many :clothes_label
end
```

I want to be able to query for only `"Blue and Aloha" or "Green and Aloha" clothes`:

```
Clothes.for_label_classfications(
  color: ['blue', 'green'],
  style: ['aloha']
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `label` association in the `Clothes` model:

```
has_one :label, through: : clothes_label
```

And then define the below scope in `Clothes` model that returns the clothes based on label classification:

```
scope :for_label_classfications, -> (classification:, name:) { joins(:label).where(label: {classification: classification, name: name}) }
```

Now, when you can run multiple queries to get the clothes based on classification and combine them:

```
Clothes.for_label_classfications(classification: 'style', name: ['aloha']) +
Clothes.for_label_classfications(classification: 'color', name: ['blue', 'green'])
```

Or you can simply run a single query as well assuming different classifications can't not have data with the same name. For example, style classification can't have green as name:

```
Clothes.for_label_classfications(classification: ['style', 'color'], name: ['aloha', 'blue', 'green'])
```

Comment: I think you meant & instead of +? How to combine those AND into a single query?

Comment: No, I meant +. + adds the result arrays of the two queries and acts as an OR operator. The second query is already a single query assuming different classifications can't not have data with the same name.

Comment: I couldn't chain the query to perform chain the logic together using AND, e.g. Clothes.for_label_classfications(classification: 'style', name: ['aloha']).for_label_classfications(classification: 'color', name: ['blue', 'green'])

Comment: what about the one I suggested- `Clothes.for_label_classfications(classification: 'style', name: ['aloha']) +
Clothes.for_label_classfications(classification: 'color', name: ['blue', 'green'])`

Comment: Or this one- `Clothes.for_label_classfications(classification: ['style', 'color'], name: ['aloha', 'blue', 'green'])`

Comment: neither of those does the and query, right?

Comment: based on your question, this is exactly what you needed.